# getent returns different value than /etc/password

Tags: bash, passwd

I'm running into an issue where the /bin/bash shell doesn't load for a new user. It says

```
Could not chdir to home directory /bin/bash: Not a directory
-sh: /bin/bash/.profile: Not a directory
```

So I checked the home folder and that's fine:

```
drwx------   2 testuser testuser    76 Jun 10 16:52 testuser
```

Looking at `/etc/passwd` in less it shows the file as

```
testuser:x:1417:10:/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

but if I type `getent passwd testuser` I get this:

```
testuser:x:1417:10:/home/testuser:/bin/bash:
```

Notice that trailing colon. Looking at other users, this is obviously the issue, but where is it occurring? As shown above the /etc/password above looks fine.

EDIT:
`pwck -r` returns the following

```
invalid password file entry
delete line 'testuser:x:1417:10:/home/testuser:/bin/bash'? No
no matching password file entry in /etc/passwd
delete line 'testuser:!!:18423:0:99999:7:::'? No
pwck: no changes
```

Comment: TBH they both look messed up to me - the GECOS (fullname) field appears to be missing in both cases, so the home dir is being read as the GECOS information; the login shell as the home dir; then the (optional) login shell is defaulting to `sh`. What does `sudo pwck -r` report?

Comment: @steeldriver added the output above for reference.

Comment: @steeldriver that was the solution. Feel free to post as an answer to get the points. The admin that set it up said he had copied from another machine (solaris?) so I just modified the line to `testuser:x:1417:10::/home/testuser:/bin/bash`

Comment: Read `man -a passwd;man -k shadow`. Each `/etc/passwd` entry MUST have a matching entry in `/etc/shadow`.